# How to print this webpage without cutting divs in half? Nothing I try works

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing, page-break

I've read through every SO question and article I can find on the topic and have tried every suggestion, but nothing has made any difference. I just need to print webpages like [this one](https://www.mlb.com/gameday/giants-vs-dodgers/2022/07/24/662682#game_state=final,game_tab=play-by-play,game=662682) on mlb.com without cutting things in half at the page breaks. It might seem trivial but it's for someone who has been wrongfully imprisoned and can't do anything but sit and read for the next few years (and is a huge baseball fan), so any help would really be appreciated and make a difference.

I've tried many variations of the following, which I inserted at the bottom of the webpage's body (I also tried the bottom of its head) using Chrome's (and Firefox's) developer tools:

```html
<style type="text/css">
    @media print {
        .view-header, .action, .pitches-exist {
            break-inside: avoid !important;
            break-before: auto !important;
            overflow: visible !important;
            float: none !important;
            display: block !important;
            position: static !important;
        }
    }
</style>
```

But when I tell the browser to save/print a PDF, things are still cut off at the bottom of every page like this:

[image]

Is there any good solution to this or will I need to try to find some hack that involves changing the absolute positions or margins of elements? Of course, that wouldn't be ideal, especially since I'm not a web developer. Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

**Notes:**

- Please *don't* share any ideas that you haven't tested yourself and found to work on this particular webpage.
- I'd prefer a solution that works in Chrome but would gladly settle for one that works in another browser.

Comment: I've looked through your code and cannot find any element which has both view-header and pitches-exist class. In fact the view-header elements seem to be just that, one element with a heading in it. Are you trying to select a sibling element to view-header elements?

Comment: @AHaworth Oops, I should've separated those classes with commas so that those styles are applied to all elements that have any one of the classes. I just fixed it but it makes no difference with the issue I'm having. Any ideas?

Comment: @KJ I tried that but it doesn't make any difference. Thanks for the info but again, please only share ideas that you've tested on this webpage.

Comment: @KJ I'm pretty sure you just got lucky there since the elements' edges (almost) land right on the page breaks. If you click on the "All Plays" tab at the top and then try different innings and show the pitches of more plays, most of them will clearly show the issue.

Answer (score -2):

[image: you need modify the option]

indeed you add a bigger paper size in System printer setting

Comment: That won't help. I have to print the play-by-play, including the pitches, for the entire game, so each game will be dozens of pages.